Unable to Extract Element based on Webpage Using Google Chrome Extension
I am trying to work on a Google Chrome extension where I have an array called userCompletedQuestions to match another array called jobrequirementQn.
the idea is to 435. Non-overlapping Intervals
based on the element above, I used inspect, to try to store a string as an element in the array, "435. Non-overlapping Intervals"
For some reason, I am unable to update the array. Below is the code. For some reason, I am unable to update the array.
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    // Function to extract completed questions from the webpage
    const extractCompletedQuestions = () => {
        // Select all anchor elements that match the pattern
        const questionLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/problems/"]');

        // Array to store the extracted question topics
        let questionTopics = [];

        // Iterate over each link and extract the text
        questionLinks.forEach(link => {
            const questionText = link.textContent.trim();
            questionTopics.push(questionText);
        });

        // Store the question topics in chrome storage
        chrome.storage.local.set({ 'userCompletedQuestions': questionTopics }, function () {
            console.log('Completed questions saved:', questionTopics);
        });
    };

    // Function to initialize the pie chart
    const createChart = (data) => {
        const ctx = document.getElementById('pieChart').getContext('2d');
        return new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: data,
            options: {}
        });
    };

    const updateChartData = (chart, data) => {
        chart.data.datasets[0].data = data;
        chart.update();
    };

    // Initialize data
    const data = {
        labels: ['Completed', 'Remaining'],
        datasets: [{
            data: [0, 100], // Initial data
            backgroundColor: [
                'green', // Completed
                'lightgray' // Remaining
            ]
        }]
    };

    // Initialize chart
    let pieChart = createChart(data);

    // Add event listener to radio buttons
    const radioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');
    radioButtons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('change', function () {
            chrome.storage.local.get(['userCompletedQuestions', 'job1Questions', 'job2Questions'], function (result) {

                const userCompletedQuestions = result.userCompletedQuestions || [];
                let requiredQuestions = [];

                if (this.value === 'Job 1') {
                    requiredQuestions = result.job1Questions || [];
                } else if (this.value === 'Job 2') {
                    requiredQuestions = result.job2Questions || [];
                }

                const matchedQuestions = requiredQuestions.filter(question => userCompletedQuestions.includes(question));
                const completedPercentage = Math.round((matchedQuestions.length / requiredQuestions.length) * 100);
                const remainingPercentage = 100 - completedPercentage;

                updateChartData(pieChart, [completedPercentage, remainingPercentage]);
                console.log('Pie chart updated:', pieChart.data.datasets[0].data);
            });
        });
    });

    // Extract and store completed questions when the content script is loaded
    extractCompletedQuestions();

    // Example of extracting a specific question title if needed
    let questionText = document.querySelector('.question-title')?.innerText;
    if (questionText) {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: 'storeQuestion', question: questionText }, function (response) {
            console.log('Question data sent to background:', response);
        });
    }
});

is it wrong that I try to inspect the webpage element and try to store it?

How does this code run and how it's declared? Start by debugging it in devtools with breakpoints to ensure it even runs. For example, to access a web page you need a content script, in which case DOMContentLoaded event is not needed and won't be fired because the content script already runs at DOMContentLoaded. Note that each context in an extension has its own devtools.

I did add print statement to help my debugging but it seem how I anchor elements that match the pattern is incorrect. the proof is that my array is empty
// Select all anchor elements that match the pattern
const questionLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[href*="/problems/"]');
    let questionTopics = [];

    questionLinks.forEach(link => {
        const questionText = link.textContent.trim();
        questionTopics.push(questionText);
    });

this is part of the content script, as declare in my manifest

Use devtools to debug your code and see the state of DOM at the exact moment when it runs. You'll probably see there are no matching elements at this point, which means they are added later and you can use MutationObserver to detect them or just re-run the code in setInterval.
